# Sqlalchemy.orm module makes kivy app crash

Tags: sqlalchemy, kivy

I am developping a simple app in kivy to label data for my database. To do so, I use functions from sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.orm.
When I test the code on my computer, everything works fine, and I also can compile it into an apk, but the app instantly crashes on my phone.
I'm using Python 3.8.10 in a ubuntu venv and kivy 2.3.0.
Also, the sqlalchemy printed on my computer (2.0.25) differ from the one printed on my phone (1.3.3)

```
Here are main.py lines that may cause trouble :
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import numpy as np
__version__="2.3.0"


from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base=declarative_base()


class Level(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'levels'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, index=True)
    autre = Column(String)
    comparaison = Column(String)
    alliteration = Column(String)
    antithese = Column(String)
    metaphore = Column(String)
    enumeration = Column(String)
```

and here is the relevant part of my build.spec file :

```
# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = 


# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1
```

I've spent a lot of time testing my code by commenting each part to see which was causing the crash. It seems that the sqlalchemy.orm module is responsible for it. When i comment these lines, I can start the app but it crashes when they are not commented.

I also used adb logcat to see the errors from the execution of the app on my phone, but I haven't seen anything that can help me to spot the error.